# Rails Migration Generated Join Table Schema But No File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations, rails-models

I created a join table for a HABTM association in my Rails app. It created the table in the schema, but it never generated a model file in the app. Will it still work? Why did it not generate a file?

**Here is my migration:**

```
class CreateBooksAuthorsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books_authors, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :book_id
      t.integer :author_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Models**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :feeds
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to explicitly generate a model; it doesn't happen as a by-product of creating a join table.

A `has_and_belongs_to_many` association doesn't actually need a model class representing the association. It is supposed to be just a join table so what you've set up is exactly right.

The other option for such associations is a `has_many through:` association which uses an intermediate, or join, class. This is discussed in more details in the [rails guide for associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many). You would have to generate that joining model yourself though.